# controls positions missed when maximized window in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I was dragged the controls on the form and when i run it and maximized the window the controls don't keep on the same place which i put it on.

how to keep controls in the same place when the window is maximized ??

this is the XAML code:

```
     <Window x:Class="Wpf_App1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_App1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
            <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517" Stretch="Fill" Source="C:\Users\Moath\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Wpf_App1\Wpf_App1\Images\LoginScr.jpg"/>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="310,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16" Width="120
                         " Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                    <TextBox.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="None"/>
                    </TextBox.Background>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16
                         " Width="120
                         " >
                    <TextBox.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="None"/>
                    </TextBox.Background>
                </TextBox>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you provide your xaml?

Comment: @sam the code was added to question

Comment: Ok, than what do you mean by keeping controls in the same place? Keep them (after window's maximizing) in the exact same place of your monitor? All alignments and margins in xaml are relative to their parents (top parent is `Window` itself). Currently your content is aligned to the top left corner, and inner grid have big (310) left margin.

Comment: the window in the application with width "525" and height "350" and i put the two text boxes on this window but if i maximize the window the width will be larger than "525" and height also and the text boxes positions changed that is what i mean

Comment: when maximize window the text boxes will appear in the middle of the window and i want them to be in the top left of the window

Comment: Just created new project and copied your xaml - textboxes stays at their place with the same size. Can you post screenshot?

Comment: no i can't post screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** in your 3rd Inner `Grid` you are setting `Margin="310,112,0,0"` that is the cause of your problem. The `Margin` is work like this `Margin="left,top,right,bottom"` so you set the `left Margin` to 310 and `top Margin` to 112 that is why the `textbox` not in top left always. try to set the `Margin` to 0.

so it will look like this:

`<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122">`